# XAML Visibility Binding not working unless set in xaml.cs

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I've been trying to set up a "downloading..." popup as a rectangle with its visibility set programmatically in the related viewModel. If I set the boolean in the xaml.cs file it works perfectly but obviously it needs to be set in the viewmodel and it just won't change its visibility if done so.

I've checked on previous solutions involving raising the propertyChanged event and setting the binding two-way.

```
<Rectangle 
    Width="400" 
    Height="200"
    x:Name="popup" 
    Fill="Red" 
    Visibility="{Binding PopupIsVisible, Converter={StaticResource ResBoolToVisibilityConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,         Mode=TwoWay}" />


private bool popupIsVisible;
public bool PopupIsVisible
{
    get { return popupIsVisible; }
    set
    {
         Set(ref popupIsVisible, value);
         RaisePropertyChanged("PopupIsVisible");
    }
}
```

EDIT: as requested, here's the Converter

```
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool val;
        try
        {
            val = (bool)value;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }

        if(val)
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            return Visibility.Hidden;
        }

    }
```

EDIT2: The popup should be visibile either by pressing a button or by waiting 10 seconds on the view, oddly enough it gets shown only with the second scenario which is launched with the following code:

```
        worker = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (cycle)
            {
                // Check for cancellation 
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                LoadProcessList();

                Task.Delay(TIME_TO_REFRESH).Wait();
            }

        }, cancellationToken);
```

Any ideas?

FINAL EDIT
I managed to solve it by encasing the function containing the changes to the boolean as below:

```
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            LoadProcessList();
        });
```

thanks to @lionthefox for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Your binding is correct. I'm pretty sure you are missing the link between your View and ViewModel. Try to set the DataContext of your View to this ViewModel and check if getters/setters are triggered when they should be.

Comment: As a note, calling `RaisePropertyChanged` is redundant when you already use `Set`. Also `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` and `Mode=TwoWay` are pointless.

Comment: Please add a source of ResBoolToVisibilityConverter as well.

Comment: Some hints: 1) use `nameof(PopupIsVisible)` instead of the string for Refactoring purposes. 2) What @Clemens wrote.

Comment: @lionthefox
The getter and setter are correctly triggered, therefore proving the Datacontext has been linked to the correct viewModel.
also
 Clemens:
yes, I was aware of that but I was getting desperate ^^'

Comment: To be clear, (in debug mode) you have *two* breakpoints, one in the converter and in the Viewmodels `PopupIsVisible`. When you do your action, do both breakpoints hit?

Comment: Yes, although I noticed that the breakpoint in the converter gets hit twice in a row, while the one on the viewmodel is hit only once as expected.

Comment: @Faby That's good. Set a brakepoint in your converter and debug through to check if it receives a value if the Visiblity is returned as expected when pressing the button

Comment: @lionthefox Yes, the visibility is set as it's supposed to be

Comment: @Faby I assume you use Visual Studio. Please find the Rectangle in the Visual Tree, right click and choose Show Properties. This will open the Live Property Explorer. Here you can live check if the Visibility is correct.

Comment: Also, use `Task.Run()` instead of `Task.Factory` if you don't pass any additional parameters and use `async await` instead of `.Wait()`. Here is a guidline to async programming in c#, i found really useful [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: @lionthefox I've checked the Live Property Explorer and even when the popup is correctly shown, the Evaluated Value is still hidden. I'll give a look to the guideline you suggested, thank you so much!

Comment: @Faby that's weird... Sorry, i think i can't really help you anymore without being able to look into the whole solution. Good luck, I'm sure you will figure it out sooner or later.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there's something wrong with your binding OR the boolean to visibility converter. Here's an example that is working perfectly.

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private bool popupIsVisible;
    public bool PopupIsVisible
    {
        get
        {
            return popupIsVisible;
        }
        set
        {
            popupIsVisible = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PopupIsVisible");
        }
    }


    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Following is the XAML code,

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="ResBoolToVisibilityConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Width="400" Height="200"x:Name="popup" Fill="Red" Visibility="{BindingPopupIsVisible, Converter={StaticResource ResBoolToVisibilityConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Toggle" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

It is working here.